# sshd_config for denying login attempts but with an exception

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

**Summary**

I am trying to have `sshd_config` configured such that it rejects any login attempts for a specific user "foo" from source IPs starting with `10.0.0.*`. However, I now need to make an exception. I need to allow "foo" from 10.0.0.137.

**Current Config in sshd_config**

```
DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.*
```

**What I've tried**

1. It seems putting a `AllowUsers foo@10.0.0.137` above that line does not help. Not only does it not take effect (because of login attempts being denied due to `DenyUsers` line), but it also rejects login attempts of other users.
2. Reading the manual about **[DenyUsers](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5)**, I understand that the server is capable of handling patterns too. (Cool!) Looking at the **[PATTERNS](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE)** section it seems that its able to exclude a certain kind of patterns too. (Awesome!). But the manual doesn't much talk about using the patterns in a `user@host` format. (Grrr..). People with higher reputation might be able to look at my answer that has been deleted. The following patterns do not work:

   ```
   DenyUsers !foo@10.0.0.137,foo@10.0.0.*
   ```

   OR

   ```
   DenyUsers !foo@10.0.0.137
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.*
   ```

<strike>I am looking for a way to construct a pattern according to what I've written in the summary section above. I have an idea: `DenyUsers !foo@10.0.0.137,foo@10.0.0.*`</strike>. I would would usually try these sorts of things before posing a question, but I wouldn't want to get myself locked out of my machine because SSH server's failure to start owing to bad configuration.

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04, OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4

Comment: Could you create a secondary user, and test blocking with it?  Or use it as your remote access while you test the other account?  You could then just delete it after testing.

Comment: I'd recommend (if you're going to be faffing around with sshd settings on a remote computer you don't have physical access to) that you run a second copy of sshd on a different port for recovery purposes if you break the main config (this is what Ubuntu's upgrade process does automatically)

Comment: @NDGeek: My concern was more about SSHD not coming up at all (no sshd process) because of bad config file; not much about losing user level access.  Thanks qasdfdsaq: running a second copy of sshd is a good suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work:

```
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.?
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.??
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.2*
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.10?
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.11?
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.12?
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.14?
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.15?
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.16?
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.17?
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.18?
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.19?
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.130
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.131
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.132
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.133
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.134
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.135
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.136
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.138
   DenyUsers foo@10.0.0.139
   AllowUsers foo@10.0.0.137
```

The question mark stands for *exactly* one character, the asterisk for *0 or more characters*.

Comment: His desired ip is `.137` not `.37`. Can you please explain that `DenyUsers` line? What does `!` mean?

Comment: @RJFalconer Thanks for point out the mistake, I have corrected it.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: Haha, I had actually thought of this– as my last resort :). But I believe there's some way of making use of patterns combinations ( `!` for negation of pattern and `,` for logical AND; linked in the question) for this purpose.

Comment: @Thrustmaster Documentation on Patterns is very scarce but you have only two primary connectives, the unary ! (negation), and the AND. Also, while you have the operator FOR EVERY, you do not have parentheses.  So, how do you make an OR? If you can make an OR, what you say is true. Or a NAND,if you will. Until then...

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: Yes, absence of parantheses and OR operator is a hindrance. But the workaround would be to have multiple `DenyUsers` lines. At the moment, I am going to launch a second sshd instance, and try the pattern I have put up in my original question..

Comment: I went ahead and used your solution! Downside of agile teams – time is at a premium and you dont get to experiment much, sadly. :(